# How to set .net framework trust level to Low for C#.net application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a C# app running in fully trusted zone "My computer". I have checked trust level of application under "Microsoft .net Framework configuration tool" and it is showing as "**unrestricted**" which means fully trusted.  Now I want to set this trust level to low for application. How can I achieve this ? It would be better if this can be achieved without code changes of application. Can we mention these settings in config file of application ?  Assembly is not signed.
I have tried to modify trust level from "**Microsoft .net Framework configuration tool -> Runtime Security Policy -> Trust assembly**"  but getting error message as "**Hash for the assembly cannot be generated**". 
I think this error because of my assembly is not signed.
**Can we have a application with trust level set to low, running in zone with trust level as Fully trusted**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The assembly must have a strong name. Sign it and you will be able to modify its trust level.

Comment: I alredy tried this one , as I mentioned in question I am getting error AS "Hash for the assembly cannot be generated"

Comment: This assembly actually refers to many other dlls , so do I need to sign all those assemblies ? Any alternatives ? can we set level in app confguration ?

Comment: That is one of the major problems, I find, with signed assemblies. If you refer to other DLLs, they need to be signed too, and often you cannot do so. But there is a tool to do this; check out http://brutaldev.com/post/2013/10/18/NET-Assembly-Strong-Name-Signer.

Comment: You need to SIGN, thus making it more trustable, to properly distrust it? Oh wow .NET

Comment: Thanks for suggesting tool. Signed all dlls. Now I am facing error "Unable to load assembly". I am using "Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration" and application is built using .net 3.5. So do I need to use "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Configuration"? actually it is not installed on my m/c

Comment: There is no such thing; you have to use the 2.0 Framework Configuration. Do you get any more information than "Unable to load" ?

Comment: @Roy Dictus : Thanks for help. One basic question, I am new to this area. This .Net trust levels are applicable only for web applications or it is applicable for desktop apps also ? because I trying to apply this for desktop app. If it is not, then I have wasted whole day.

Comment: @sagar: It is not just for web applications, it is for any .NET assembly, so that includes WinForms or WPF applications.